# How to check if "Prefer Closed Caption + SDH" checkbox is selected for Accessibility under Hearing Section in Swift (Cocoa macOS)

Tags: swift, cocoa, avfoundation, accessibility, avplayer

I am working on an Accessibility feature where closed captions need to be shown for supporting media assets urls in AVPlayer. the CC should only when the user has enabled the "Prefer Closed Caption + SDH" checkbox under Accessibility inside System Preferences.

iOS has static var **isClosedCaptioningEnabled** property for **UIAccessibility**  class, is there a similar property in macOS using Swift?

As per ([Subtitles won't display if closed caption is off in system settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56387787/subtitles-wont-display-if-closed-caption-is-off-in-system-settings))

After implementation, the closed caption shows always, and not dependent on Accessibility settings.

[image]

[image]